# stored procedure sql server trying to eliminate dups (many to many relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

A little difficult wording this properly..

- Table A has a Role
- Table B ties Roles to Assets
- Table C is for Assets

There is a many to many relationship from Roles to Assets.

Based on a column bit value in Assets.. I want to map that to roles w/ that value.  But I get numerous roles because of the many to many relationship.  So what I want is if ANY asset has bit = 1 return the equivalent role(s).  I do not want duplicate PK for the roles.  My query which returns duplicate roles (by PK) looks like this.

```
select rls.Role_ID, 
       asset.Asset_ID, 
       Asset.Is_Public

        from Roles rls
            inner join Role_Asset on rls.Role_ID = Role_Asset.Role_ID
            inner join Asset on Role_Asset.Asset_ID = asset.Asset_ID 
            where Asset.Is_Public =1
```

problem being I turn numerous rolesID because of the many to many relationship.. If any public asset is tied to a role.. I want that role, but only that role.  If a role is tied to numerous assets and one is 1 and the other is 0. I still want it returned (so if any public asset it tied to a role return it).

AND THE INVERSE (AKA IS_PUBLIC=0)

Comment: have you tried to group by Role_id?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an EXISTS statement in your WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT rls.Role_ID
FROM Roles rls
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Role_Asset ra
    WHERE ra.Role_ID = rls.Role_ID
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Asset a
        WHERE a.Asset_ID = ra.Asset_ID
        AND a.Is_Public = 1
    )
);
```

Comment: I thought maybe at first.   if I change a.Ispublic=0, I still return the Role that is connected to the public Asset.  I should be able the flip that bit and get the inverse.  The two queries unioned together should then return all roles.

Comment: This gets the answer you asked for, which was "If any public asset is tied to a role.. I want that role, but only that role. If a role is tied to numerous assets and one is 1 and the other is 0. I still want it returned (so if any public asset it tied to a role return it)."

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the relationship between both in a 3rd table called Role_Assets, therefore you will have to create a left join instead of INNER, because the inner join will exclude the values which do not match. Furthermore, you will have to select the ROLEID from the composite table, instead of using the ROLES_table. In that way you are going to end up with all the roles, which are having public asset as TRUE. In other words, you result set will look like:

```
     ROLE ID          ASSET ID      PUBLIC
      1                  1            1
      1                  2            1
      1                  3            1
      2                  1            0
      2                  2            0
```

Comment: I've used left outer already.. I only left it as inner because it main no difference.  In the example you posted it should only return Role_ID 1.  I'm getting the results exactly I use posted.  I don't want to have to sort through duplicates results in code later.